# unexpected .pc files setting up home brew

Tags: ruby, xcode, homebrew, installation

I am completely new to programming and am trying to get my computer set up to code ruby. When I downloaded xCode and installed command line tools, I then went to terminal to install Homebrew. When I run brew doctor after everything, I get this:

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
guest-wireless-207-151-229-215:~ trev$ brew doctor
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
```

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc

I have no idea what this is or where to even start to fix it and can't find it on google or anywhere on here. Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config.old 
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config.old
```

If that doesn't work or you want to undo run:

```
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config.old /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
mv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config.old /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
```